# Full page caching (FastCGI) + CSRF token (Server side loading SSI, ESI, Ajax) + Nginx

Tags: nginx, caching, csrf, fastcgi, esi

first: I have been reading a lot of SO posts, and did not find a satisfying answer. I hope I did not miss the answer.

**Situation**:

- I'm running a Laravel application (PHP 7.3)
- I implemented a full page cache using FastCGI (php-fpm) and Nginx
- It works great, BUT dynamic things like the csrf token are not refreshed
- My Goal: get a full cached page, but with the right CSRF token for user session

**What I've tried**:

- I digged into [Nginx SSI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html), but only could make it work with .html file. Here I wanted to include a simple .php file (that include laravel Core) to retrieve the output of `csrf_token()`

  - I tried with `file` and `virtual` includes, with `.php` file and API routes. It never worked in my Blade templates. (Strange as I understood, it's based on response content-type like text/html). Even a basic `<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->` does not work and is stripped out by Nginx (not in response).
  - same tests in a `.html` file **worked**. I could include my .php file that has my token
- I looked into ESI (Edge Side Loading), but it seems that there is not support for Nginx yet... too bad.

  - It seems possible to use Varnish as a proxy to get ESI working. But it's a lot of changes to our infrastructure.

**What I have left**:

- In the end, the only solution I can think of is to make an Ajax API request onLoad to get the token. On every page load. It does not seem a really good approach but, I'm out of options (am I?).
- Maybe I can trick Nginx to think my root index.php is HTML and so get SSI to work? ([inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634658/nginx-ssi-remote-uri-access-does-not-work))
- SSI/ESI seems exactly what I need. But it also seems to be "an old" technology. Still, I couldn't find real alternatives.

**Questions**:

- is SSI only possible with HTML files?
- is installing everything for ESI worth?
- is Ajax the only solution I have?
- is there something else I could have missed?

Thanks a lot. I know there are similar questions, but I could not find a definitive answer to this situation.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm having a similar problem with Fastcgi cache where I don't want it applied to requests with Authorization header in them

Comment: I think you can configure Nginx (Apache also certainly) to disable your fastcgi_cache (with required config options, and a variable to set them) depending header value/content/presence (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970620/nginx-reject-request-if-header-is-not-present-or-wrong).

Comment: Yea I managed to fix it this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378224/bypass-fastcgi-cache-when-authorization-header

Comment: I am trying to solve the same challenge. Did you find a workaround @Mtxz?

Comment: Well, in the end, I added an Ajax request `head` returning a CRSF token on page load. This token is stored and then used for the next queries or submits. If you find a better way, I would love to hear it!